# How to enter command line argument with docops?

Tags: rust, docopt

How can I enter command line arguments in Rust using docopts? I'd like to simply be able to enter a u8 in a vector and parse it with docopts.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the interest of getting better answers, please  take care to [ask better questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In this case, you should show some example code of what you tried. Or maybe some search results for things you've looked up but don't understand. At the very least, you could write some example code (or pseudocode) that better explains what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`std::env::args`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.args.html) method to obtain an iterator. Then, you can use `.collect` on the iterator to get a vector of `String`s.

```
use std::env;
fn main () {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    println!("{:?}", args);
}
```

Example output:

```
simon@Simon-Desktop:~$ rustc t.rs 
simon@Simon-Desktop:~$ ./t abc def
["./t", "abc", "def"]
```